# Difference between (25) and @(25)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnumber

I have been brushing up on my objective-c and one of the exercises that I am working on deals with UIInterpolatingMotionEffect objects. 2 properties from that class are `minimumRelativeValue` and `maximumRelativeValue`. In the exercise they have them as the following:

```
motionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-25);
motionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(25);
```

I know that in obj-c you use @ for the following (from wikipedia):

```
Used to avoid taking english words and making them reserved (for example, you can't have a variable called float in C/Objective-C because this is a reserved word).
```

With that being said, what would be the difference between using `@(-25)` and `(-25)` in the above example?

Answer (score 3):

25 is a number. @(25) is an NSNumber object with value 25. It is equal to

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:25];
```

In some cases you have to wrap numbers with NSNumber. For example you can not add number to NSArray / NSMutableArray.

You may read more about Objective C literals here https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-06-22-objective-c-literals.html

Comment: That is a response to the subject line, not to the question. Or it is wrong by 50. :-)

Comment: IMHO my answer is shorter then yours and has better explanation.

Comment: Yes, it is much shorter but slightly wrong. He was asking for -25 or (-25) respectively. Of course, that does not matter very much.

Comment: To be precise, `25` is not just a number, but a *scalar data type*, as opposed to a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

(-25) is just -25 with brackets around. You can add backets to lots of numerical or logical expessions without (or sometimes with) changing its value.

The @ is one of the object creation shortcuts in objective-c. In this case it is equivalent to @-25 (Frankly, I am not sure whether there needs to be the brackets here because of the minus) which is equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithInt:-25].

See more of them here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: The parentheses makes a difference between a number literal and an expression literal. The result is the same though.